# the second button overwrites the first button

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton

When I click on the first button, the information about the second button are launched.

I did a print just before the connect and I pass the good informations so I don't understand

Here's my code :

```
    def load_list_program(self):
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        select_ = []
        from_ = ["Programme"]
        actualY = -2
        for y in range(date.year - 1, date.year + 2):
            actualY += 1
            res = requetes_pre_def.find_prog_by_year(str(y))
            print(res)
            for prog in res:
                prog.print_prog()
                print(prog.ien)
                prog_year_button = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton(prog.prog_name)
                prog_year_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.open_prog(prog))
                prog_year_button.setCheckable(True)
                prog_year_button.toggle()
                prog_year_button.setObjectName(prog.prog_name)
                if actualY == -1:
                    self.zoneY1.addWidget(prog_year_button)
                elif actualY == 0:
                    self.zoneY2.addWidget(prog_year_button)
                elif actualY == 1:
                    self.zoneY3.addWidget(prog_year_button)
        print("TEST")
```

Comment: `prog_year_button.clicked.connect(lambda *args, prog=prog: self.open_prog(prog))`

Comment: Thank you versy much  eyllanesc it's working !